# Move team service account from personal to work subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have an account in VSTS, which have both personal and work account. I have a project named `abc.visualstudio.com` under my work account. I would like to change this project to my personal account.

Changing ownership to a different person is quiet easy in VSTS. Changing a project from one directory to another of the same person is a bit tricky and I am struggling to get this done.

Comment: Do you mean move a team project from a VSTS to another VSTS?

Comment: No. Lets say, `abc.visualstudio.com` is a team that I have under my personal login of xyz@hotmail.com in VSTS. Now, I want to move this team to work/office login of the same xyz@hotmail.com.

Comment: What's the different after changing directory?

Comment: I use personal directory for azure VM. Would like to have the VSTS too in the same directory. Plus, there is a bizspark subscription in personal directory. Moving from work/office directory would help me use the same subscription.

Comment: Since you mentioned that the VSTS account is currently under your work account, I suspect that it is backed by an Azure AD, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It is backed by an Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "xyz@hotmail.com" is the current owner of the VSTS account and then disconnect the VSTS account from the linked Azure AD, the owner will switch to the Microsoft Account with "xyz@hotmail.com".

One important thing you need to know is that disconnecting VSTS from AAD will cause the other users who use the work account cannot sign in. So you need to make sure that all the other users also switch to microsoft account.

Comment: I am still stuck. There are two places where I could find AzureAD. (1) portal.azure.com, (2)classic portal. In 'work account', I could enter the classic portal. In 'personal account', it says no subscription found. Even though it says no subscription, if I try using 'portal.azure.com' I can find the domain names under Azure Active Directory --> Domain Names.

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu Sign in classic portal with your work account. Select "VISUAL STUDIO TEAM SERVICE" and then click on the VSTS account you'd like to disconnect. Click "Disconnect" button under "Configure" tab.

Comment: You need to click "New" button to link your VSTS account first if you didn't see your VSTS account in the list.

Comment: The issue had been resolved. There was some backend bug with the Azure portal which did not allow me to move the project. I had raised a support request and had got it resolved. Thanks for your various suggestions.